# Unwanted package name prompt with create-vite

Tags: vite

Using [create-vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project) to scaffold a new Vite project produces an unwanted prompt for a package name if you try to vary the target folder path in any way.

So this works fine:

```bash
npm create vite test-vite-app2 -- --template react

Scaffolding project in /home/mikey/Development/test-vite-app2...

Done. Now run:

  cd test-vite-app2
  npm install
  npm run dev
```

No prompt for a package name.  When I open test-vite-app2/package.json, the package's "name" entry is set to "test-vite-app2".  Perfect.  This is just what I wanted .

But if the target folder is a nested sub-folder like this:

```bash
npm create vite temp/test-vite-app2 -- --template react
```

I get prompted to set the package name, with the default being set to a concatenation of the folder structure.   Errmm...why ?

Same happens if I try and target a folder at the same level as my current folder:

```bash
npm create vite ../test-vite-app2 -- --template react
```

Now I get a suggested package name that is the target folder but with a dash at the front of it.

Is there any way to stop this unwanted package name prompt from happening?  Or at least, have the prompt preset to something sensible?

Comment: What would have it do instead?  Slash is not valid as a package name.  It can't guess what you want.

Comment: This might better be asked here (either as a feature request / bug report): https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues

Comment: @TimRoberts, use the lowest level folder as the package name, so  "test-vite-app2" in all cases above.  Oh and no prompt!

Comment: @AngYC when I ask questions like this as a Github repo issue, I'm usually told "this isn't a helpdesk site; why don't you try stackoverflow?"  .   I will go there if nobody here can answer though.  And thanks for your response.

Comment: The documentation specifies that parameter is the project name, not the folder.  The folder creation is a side effect.  Names with a slash are invalid, so it has to ask what you meant.  If you think it's a bug, file it with the github repo, but they're going to say it is by design.  It is, of course, easy to work around.  Create it local and `mv` it into place.

Comment: @TimRoberts,  yes `mv` might be the workaround.  I'll definitely keep that one in mind if I can find no other way to do what I want.  Thanks for that one .

Answer (score 0):

[ScreenShot of my Terminal is attached here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWPGb.png)
When the terminal prompts for "Package name:" while creating react app through vite, just enter whatever is in the placeholder(the placeholder will have the name as that of the Project name that you have entered, but in lower case).

Comment: I don't want a prompt, as I said in my original post.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that. @ChillyPenguin

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the project name, the name must be in lowercase letters. With capital letters, we end up creating an unwanted package.